# regex works in regex tester but not in pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, html

Its quite a simple but in my opinion weird problem i basically have this regex and entered a few tests and they work.

```
(?=^\*)|(?=^.{1,254}$)(^(?:(?!\d+\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\{\}]{1,63}\.?)+(?:[a-zA-Z\{\}]{1,})$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/hU6tP0/2

But when i try to use it in html it fails. But if i test it in javascript it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/ek6kby2q/9/

I don't have much knowledge at all about regex so maybe anyone know whats going wrong or got any tips to make the regex better is welcome.

Comment: without your input we will not be able to help you

Comment: the regex101 has a unit test with some possible matches.
The jfiddle has *.com that is one of the matches that passes in the regex101 but not in the html.

Comment: it is passing in given fiddle

Comment: http://oi65.tinypic.com/2md2b01.jpg It doens't pass it for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an html attribute, the pattern must match all the string from the beginning to the end, that's why `(?=^\*)` fails to do it, since it matches zero characters.

Use this pattern instead:

```
\*.*|(?!.{255})(?:[A-Za-z_{}-][\w{}-]{0,62}\.?)+[A-Za-z{}]+
```

*(You can omit the anchors since they are implicit)*

Comment: This seems to solve the issue.

Just wondering if you could help me out by making the regex work so this works

`*.com`

but for example this doesn't
`*<com>` or `*!com!`

In any case i will select your answer because i now understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: @jermey: I have tested `*<com>` and `*!com!` in your fiddle and it works too. If you don't want to validate these two cases, replace `.*` with something more explicit.

Comment: I would like them not to work. Basically this part `\*.*|` should be changed so the regex says something like:

The beginning of the string can be a `*` but the rest should still follow the current regex in my original post -  `\*.*|`

Instead of what it says now.

if its starts with a `*` then ignore the entire regex

Comment: @jermey: I see. In this case try to change your pattern like this: `(?!.{255})(?:\*|(?:\*\.)?(?:[A-Za-z_{}-][\w{}-]{0,62}\.?)+[A-Za-z{}]+)` that allows a single `*` or all the subpattern starting with an optional `*.` *(if you don't need the dot, replace `(?:\*\.)?` with `\*?`)*

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly. This showed me how helpless i am when it comes to regex. Need to go find a tutorial and practice when i have the time. :(

Comment: @jermey: you only need more practice. Correction: if you don't need the dot, replace `(?:\*\.)?` with `(?:\*\.?)?`